# GeoTools 2.6.5: Cannot get JMapFrame to work because of problem with processStylers

Tags: java, geotools

I am trying to get JMapFrame to work to visualize some feature. Unfortunately I keep getting errors although this test app can be started. Toolbars etc. are shown.

```
18.02.2011 16:44:38 org.geotools.renderer.lite.StreamingRenderer paint

SEVERE: null

java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.geotools.renderer.lite.StreamingRenderer.processStylers(StreamingRenderer.java:1771)
at org.geotools.renderer.lite.StreamingRenderer.paint(StreamingRenderer.java:722)
```

([full stack trace here](http://pastebin.com/rKA8dGFc))

My source code is [here](http://pastebin.com/JNwCdmwa). (And pom.xml [here](http://pastebin.com/jx3QPYhE))

I assume the problem must be anywhere in "myStyle". Is there maybe a default style?

Answer (score 1):

This one looks like the culprit:

```
Graphic graph = sb.createGraphic(null, new Mark[] { testMark }, null,
            sb.literalExpression(1), sb.attributeExpression("size"),
            sb.attributeExpression("rotation"));
```

you are creating graphic marker with a *null* graphic.
I'm pretty sure you're hitting this issue (not an issue imo, more an error on the user side):

http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GEOT-1772

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Unfortunately I cannot test it but if it works for anyone, I'll accept it.

Comment: well, voting up wouldn't be a bad start ;-)

Answer (score 0):

From a quick scan it seems that you are trying to symbolize a line with a PointSymbolizer. The first thing to try would be to load a simple SLD file that you know works (build and test it in UDig). This would allow you be sure that it isn't a problem with your features. Then I'd add a logger and turn up the logging level before stepping through the program in a debugger to see what exactly is null.